# Marking the mean on the X-axis of the plot

Tags: r, plot

I want the value of the mean to appear on the X-axis. But I have only managed to get it to appear above the X-axis:

[image: img]

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu, sd=s), from=0, to=80, xlab="Horas", ylab="f(x)")
abline(v=mu, col='red', lty=3)
abline(v=mu - s/2, col='blue', lty=3)
abline(v=mu + s/2, col='blue', lty=3)
legend("topright", legend=c("", ""), 
       title=(paste("N(", mu, ", ", s, ")")), 
       title.adj=0, lty=0, lwd=0, box.lty=0)
text(mu, 0, labels=mu)
box()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make this more dynamic, e.g. the curve from `0` to about `2` times mu. It might look better if we had the usual rounded spacing on the x-axis, with the mean highlighted, apparently `max(pretty(mu*2/3))` doesn't work too bad. Finally, `abline`s can be drawn in one step, and `bquote` helps with dynamic expressions with equations.

```
x0 <- 0; x1 <- 2*mu

curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu, sd=s), from=x0, to=x1, xlab="Horas", ylab='', xaxt='n')
## y-lab
mtext(bquote(italic(f)~(x)), 2, 2.5)
## lines
abline(v=mu + s*c(0, 1/2, -1/2), col=c('red', 'blue', 'blue'), lty=3)
## normal x-axis
axis(1, seq(x0, x1, max(pretty(mu*2/3))))
## mu on x-axis
axis(1, mu, labels=FALSE, col='red')  
mtext(mu, side=1, line=1, at=mu, col='red')
## legend
legend('topright', legend=bquote(N(.(mu), .(s))), bty='n')
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)  ## some random mu and sd
mu <- trunc(runif(1)*100); s <- trunc(runif(1)*10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `text()` use `mtext()` (which stands for *margin text*):

```
mu <- 41; s <- 5

curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu, sd=s), from = 0, to = 80, xlab="Horas", ylab="f(x)")
abline(v=mu, col='red', lty=3)
abline(v=mu-(s/2), col='blue', lty=3)
abline(v=mu+(s/2), col='blue', lty=3)
legend("topright", legend = c("", ""), 
       title = (paste("N(",mu,",",s,")")),
       title.adj = 0, lty = 0, lwd = 0, box.lty = 0 )
mtext(mu, 1, at=mu)
box()
```

[image: pic]

You can adjust the y-position of the text with the `line =`  argument. Read `help(mtext)`.

If instead you want to add the mean not at the margin but to the x-axis itself, you would have to first suppress the drawing of original x-axis inside `curve()` by adding a `xaxt='n'` parameter. And then draw the axis manually with `axis(1)`.

Example:

```
mu <- 41; s <- 5

curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu, sd=s), from = 0, to = 80, xlab="Horas", ylab="f(x)", xaxt="n")
abline(v=mu, col='red', lty=3)
abline(v=mu-(s/2), col='blue', lty=3)
abline(v=mu+(s/2), col='blue', lty=3)
legend("topright", legend = c("", ""), 
       title = (paste("N(",mu,",",s,")")),
       title.adj = 0, lty = 0, lwd = 0, box.lty = 0 )
axis(1, at = c(0,20,41,60,80))
box()
```

[image: img2]

Comment: And it is not possible, that the value of the mean appears on the X-axis, but as part of the values and not always have to appear 0, 20, 40 and 80. That is, that 0, 20, 41 and 80 appear.

Comment: @Amelia nothing is impossible, added an example for what you want. Note that you might want to do this dynamically rather than writing 41 by hand. For that you could get the usual axis ticks with `ticks <- pretty(c(0, 80))`, and then replace the value that is closest to the mean with the mean, and call `axis(1, at = ticks)`.

Comment: But if the mean is changing, how do I take that into account. In advance, I do not know the value of the mean.

Comment: One simple solution is to show ticks at the mean, +/- 3 sd, and +/- 6 sd. Maybe something like: `axis(1, at=round(mu+s*c(-6,-3,0,3,6)))`

Comment: Glad to hear. I noticed you have several questions where you do not select an answer for acceptance. This is poor practice as it makes other people think the question is still unresolved. In order to close the questions properly please consider marking some answers as "accepted". It improves the overall hygiene of the site we are using.